# is there way to notify my app before user send sms from OS SMS System?

Tags: android, sms

the idea is , when the user send SMS from his native phone(NOT FROM MY APP) can i get notify to my application to do some checking options before i decide if i want to let user send message or stop sending message depends on my application settings ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it, bydefault Android System uses SmsManager class to send the SMS. You need to implement ContentObserver class to get the details about Out going sms.

// Code to access

```
private SmsSentObserver smsSentObserver = null;
private static final Uri STATUS_URI = Uri.parse("content://sms");

if( smsSentObserver == null )
{
    smsSentObserver = new SmsSentObserver( new Handler(), context );
    context.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(STATUS_URI, true, smsSentObserver);
}
```

// ContentObserve class

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public class SmsSentObserver extends ContentObserver 
{
    private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat  ( "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" );
    private static final Uri STATUS_URI = Uri.parse("content://sms");
    private Context context;

    public SmsSentObserver( Handler handler, Context context ) 
    {
        super(handler);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {return true;}

    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) 
    {
        try
        {
            Cursor sms_sent_cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(STATUS_URI, null, null, null, null);
            if (sms_sent_cursor != null) 
            {
                if (sms_sent_cursor.moveToFirst()) 
                {
                    if ( sms_sent_cursor.getString(sms_sent_cursor.getColumnIndex("protocol") ) == null  )
                    {
                        if ( sms_sent_cursor.getInt(sms_sent_cursor.getColumnIndex("type")) == 2 );
                        {
                            StringBuffer msgDetail = new StringBuffer();
                            msgDetail.append( "\n Sent To : " + sms_sent_cursor.getString(sms_sent_cursor.getColumnIndex("address")) );
                            msgDetail.append( "\n" + sms_sent_cursor.getString(sms_sent_cursor.getColumnIndex("body")) );
                            msgDetail.append( "\n Date : " + sdf.format( sms_sent_cursor.getLong(sms_sent_cursor.getColumnIndex("date"))) );
                            LogFile logFile = new LogFile( context );
                            logFile.appendData( msgDetail.toString().trim() , context.getString( R.string.LogFileName ) );
                            logFile = null;
                            msgDetail = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            LogFile logFile = new LogFile( context );
            logFile.appendData( context.getString( R.string.SENT_SMS_ERROR ) + e.toString() , context.getString( R.string.LogFileName ) );
            logFile = null;
        }
        finally { System.gc(); }
        super.onChange(selfChange);
    }
}
```